# Printing full path of directories

Tags: linux, command-line

I am trying to get full paths of folder and print them into a into a file.

```
ls -ltR|grep "^d"|awk -v P="$(pwd)" '{print $NF " = " P"/"$NF}'
```

I have been using this command to get paths. But they are not proper.
Ex. When trying to print path of Documents/Folder/Folder2 comes as Documents/folder2 instead of proper path.

I have tried going over directory using for loop and printing out solution like this:

```
for dir in */
do
     dir=ls -ltR|grep "^d"|awk -v P="$(pwd)" '{print $NF " = " P"/"$NF}'
     echo $dir
done
```

Comment: *find . -printf "${PWD}/%h\n"*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about simply:

```
find  ./*
```

It will print all the paths starting with '.'

If you want the absolute path try the following:

```
find  `pwd`
```